# How to check which projects are dependent on a .cpp file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, compilation

I've got a solution with many projects that are dependent on one another (large program, about ~200 projects).
Alot of these connect are compiled as static libs, and are compiled into other projects that use link time code generation.

Now, lets say i want to test something and change a single .cpp file somewhere, and i don't want to re-install the whole thing, so i just want to replace the dlls that are affected by the change.

How do i find all the dlls that were re-created and are affected by the change ?

Comment: As you mentioned - IF a lot of projects are statically linked with the code you're going to change now, you need to recompile those projects once again since those projects would not be using the dynamic libraries in the first place for this piece of code. Is it that you're asking how do you find only such projects and recompile them again ?

Comment: Just clicking "compile" will compile the needed files. Question is if there's a way to check what needs to be changed without doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a version control system (which you probably are), and you check in DLLs before deployment (which you possibly don't), you can ask the VCS what DLLs have changed.

Because that's probably the place in your workflow to have this intelligence: you want a compact deployment, you need to create a checkpoint each time you deploy (in this case by checking in your deployable objects).